# What is the proper way to reopen a file in java?

Tags: java, file-io, printwriter

I have been working on this problem for days and cannot get it to work. the problem asks me open a file and calculate the mean and then close it. Then reopen it an calculate the standard deviation. The trouble I'm having is after I calculate the mean and close the file. When I try to reopen it shows the error that cannot find the file. Here is what I have so far:

```
File fr = new File(filename);
Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(fr);

filename = inputFile.nextLine();

while(inputFile.hasNext())
{
    double number = inputFile.nextDouble();
    sum =  number + sum;

    count++;

    line = inputFile.nextDouble();
}
inputFile.close();
mean = sum / count;

//New File

File file = new File(filename);
Scanner br = new Scanner(file);

double sumB = 0;
int countB = 0;

filename = br.nextLine();
while(br.hasNext())
{
    double sumthin = br.nextDouble();
    difference =  sumthin - mean;
    sumB = sumB + Math.sqrt(difference);
    count++;
    line = br.nextDouble();
}
br.close();
Math.sqrt(sumB / count);
```

Comment: what's the error? why aren't you using `fr` (the second time)?

Comment: this is the error that shows:                                   `Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: 87.5517 (The system cannot find the file specified)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
 at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:636)
 at StatsDemo.main(StatsDemo.java:50)`

Comment: if I use the `fr` it gives me an error saying its already defined

Comment: Don't declare it, just use it. new Scanner(fr)

Comment: Take into account that you can calculate the mean and de std deviation in a single pass. It this is not homework, this could be a more efficient approach.

Answer (score 4):

You (probably) aren't opening the same file twice - you are reading a filename from the first file, then opening that second file:

```
File fr = new File(filename);
...
filename = inputFile.nextLine();
...
File file = new File(filename);
```